# Landscape mode for video player

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I am using `chewie` video player in flutter. My app does not allow landscape mode. I only want to allow chewie player fullscreen to be in landscape. The chewie player is used in a screen similar to YouTube, with recommended videos under the player. I don't want the screen itself to be displayed in landscape.

Here is the relevant code where `CustomVideoPlayer` is a widget that encapsulates the `chewie` video player.

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: CustomVideoPlayer(
            key: ValueKey(state.data.video.url),
            url: state.data.video.url,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rohan Please try below solution:

**Note:** The Chewie video player can go into landscape mode when in fullscreen, while the rest of the app remains in portrait mode.

```
CustomVideoPlayer(
  onEnterFullscreen: () => SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]),
  onExitFullscreen: () => SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]),
);
```